# GIT diff temporary file naming conventions causing problems

Tags: git, matlab, diff, simulink, tortoisegit

I'm using Tortoise GIT on windows along with MATLAB on my current project. I tried to setup MATLAB 2012b as my diff tool for Simulink models (*.slx).

But when the visdiff tool in MATLAB attempts to execute on the input generated by GIT it fails because the temporary file pull from the repository has the name ModelName-123456-left.slx.

This is an invalid model name in MATLAB. So I'm looking for a way to change the '-' in the temp-file name to '_' or similar.

It's such a simple part of GIT that I can't find documentation of it anywhere. I'm looking for help on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by creating a wrapper script for the MATLAB visdiff. This script can rename the temp files before passing them to MATLAB (and maybe rename them back afterwards).

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion. It is not possible to put the file names back after loading the diff as there is nothing appropriate to block on.

Comment: I tried to post the code here, but apparently don't know how, or if that is appropriate. It's not long, but a bit too long for a comment..

Comment: You can put it in pastebin and post a link here. But there probably just is nothing to block on. Where does git create the files? If they are created in the TEMP dir, you can just leave them anyways.

Comment: Pastebin is blocked at work.. Yep, they're in TEMP, so I stopped worrying and got back to work. Thanks!